# GRAPHCONTRACTIBILITY is NP-complete

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

> Prove that $GRAPHCONTRACTIBILITY = \{(G, H) | $ H can be obtained from
>   G by sequence of edges contractions} is NP-complete. Contraction defines as follows: given edge $(v, u)$ replace it with a vertex, which neighbors are neighbors of $u$ or $v$.

My attempt.
I want to reduce SAT to this problem. I need to construct a formula from given graph, such that if the formula is true, then the graph is contractable to the other. I have an idea that we can use edges for variables -- existing in the second graph are going to be ones, the others are going to be zeros. But it didn't work -- or I couldn't invent a good construction.

Comment: Some NP-complete problems reduce to each other easier than others.  You've probably chosen a bad pair to work on.  Try starting with another graph problem, e.g. subgraph isomorphism, which may lie closer to your desired endpoint.

Comment: After doing some examples, I am convinced that if a graph $G$ contains $K_n$, the complete graph of order $n$, then we can always edge-contract $G$ into $K_n$. If we can prove this, we are half-way done reducing $\text{CLIQUE}$ to $\text{GRAPH-CONTRACTIBILITY}$. However, the other direction does not work, edge-contracting a square gives you a triangle, which is $K_3$, but a square does not contain $K_3$. I don't know how to deal with these $``$false-positive$"$s.